# Losing the crs when writing to .gpkg with geopandas

Tags: geopandas, epsg, geopackage

When I write my .gpkg I am losing the CRS. I have tried setting the CRS with .set_crs, or adding the CRS when writing the .gpkg (which creates a fault -  "fiona._env - WARNING - dataset filename.gpkg does not support layer creation option EPSG"

My code

```
for layername in fiona.listlayers(file):                 
    vector = geopandas.read_file(file, layer=layername)
    vector.set_crs(4326)
    vector.to_file(filename + ".gpkg", layer = layername, driver='GPKG')
```

or

```
for layername in fiona.listlayers(file):                 
    vector = geopandas.read_file(file, layer=layername)
    vector.to_file(filename + ".gpkg", layer = layername, driver='GPKG', epsg=4326)
```

neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector.set_crs(4326)` does not work in place by default. You either need to assign it or specify `inplace=True`.

```py
for layername in fiona.listlayers(file):                 
    vector = geopandas.read_file(file, layer=layername)
    # vector.set_crs(4326, inplace=True)  # one option
    vector = vector.set_crs(4326)  # other option
    vector.to_file(filename + ".gpkg", layer = layername, driver='GPKG')
```

Your second attempt does not work because `to_file` does not have `espg` keyword you are trying to lose and that gets lost among arguments passed to Fiona and GDAL (which silently ignores it).